# Setting default values to null fields when mapping with jsonModel in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsonmodel

I have a model which is the response of server. one of its properties is set to null from server. How can I set it to empty string when receiving null?

Model:

```
@interface infoResponseEntity : JSONModel

@property (retain, nullable) NSString *date;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *time;
@property (retain, nullable) NSString *description;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

For more convenient you can write an extender for NSString. This is `.h` file

```
@interface NSString (Extender)

+ (BOOL)isNull:(NSString *)string;

@end
```

and this is `.m` file

```
@implementation NSString (Extender)


+ (BOOL)isNull:(NSString *)string;
{
    return (string == nil);
}

@end
```

Finally, you can use the above method for check value of property in your model.
For example:

```
if ([NSString isNull:self.date]) {

  self.date = @""; 

}
```